# spring boot : error occurred during template parsing

Tags: html, email, spring-boot, parsing, thymeleaf

I'm trying to attach a file in the mail message by using thymeleaf but at the time of sending it occurring the template parsing error.

```
package com.report.tool.services; 
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
@Service("sendmail")
public class MailSendService {

 @Autowired
MailRepository  mailrepository;
@Autowired
UserRepo userRepo;
@Autowired
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
JavaMailSender mailSender;

EmailModel datamodel;
HttpSession session;
//Mail send
 public Object sendMail(String filename) {
datamodel=new EmailModel();
try {
String usermail= "abc@abc.com"; 
//userRepo.findByToken("pPVHDe1ixjIEuNk").getEmail();


List<EmailMetaModel> mailmodel = mailrepository.findAll();
String email = null;
String pas = null;
for (Iterator iterator = mailmodel.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
EmailMetaModel emailModel = (EmailMetaModel) iterator.next();
if (emailModel.getStatus() == true) {
email = emailModel.getEmail();
pas = emailModel.getEmailpassword();
}
}

String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
// Get system properties
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
Session s = Session.getInstance(props, null);

 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s);

MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
     MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

 helper.addAttachment("logo.png", new ClassPathResource("Zeronsec.png"));

Context context = new Context();
//context.setVariable( );
String html = templateEngine.process("email-template", context);

helper.setTo(usermail);
helper.setText(html, true);
helper.setSubject("Any");
helper.setFrom(email);

message.setSubject("Thymleaf mail");
message.setText(html);




Transport tr = s.getTransport("smtps");
tr.connect(host, email, pas);
tr.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");
tr.close();

 } catch (Exception sfe) {

 System.out.println(sfe);

}

return "Mail sent"; 
} 
}
```

- This file is placed in the resource folder of my project.
- I tried many possible situations and also visit many websites but not any 
  single one sole this error.
- Please help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: paste the fullstacktrace and thymeleaf file too...some parsing issue is there and ensure all the html tags are closed.

Comment: all tags are ended completely. there is no problem in the HTML file. this is the error which I'm getting: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/templates/email-template.html]")

Answer (score 1):

That's issue with HTML template only, with spring you need properly formatted HTML, make sure all tags are closed.